# WooCommerce product gallery edit image

Tags: woocommerce, gallery

How can you edit image details (caption, alt etc) once you added image to product gallery? I can only remove the image, then add image again, where I can edit image details in Media Library. If this is not possible, could this metabox be extended with code so a button is added that would open this image in Media library?

[image]

Is there a hook or similar (for where this metabox is built) where I could add a button above the image (then I will use javascript to attach click to button to open wp media library with this image selected using attachment id)

Comment: Go to your Media Library and click on the image..?

Comment: it seems high inneficient to go through all your media library images to select exact one. is there a hook or similar where I could add a button above the image (then I will use javascript to attach click to button to open wp media library with this image selected using attachment id)

Comment: Just looking for the same option too

Comment: Ok, let this be an answer, here is the solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236817/open-media-frame-and-select-an-attachment